# PyQGIS Raster Band Stats - Access pixel values of raster layer

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I am trying to access individual pixel values in a raster layer I'm working with. I can use QgsRasterBandStats to get some information about the raster layer with the following code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
print("Active Layer: ", layer.name())
provider = layer.dataProvider()
extent = layer.extent()
stats = provider.bandStatistics(1, QgsRasterBandStats.All) 
print("min value =", stats.minimumValue)
print("max value =", stats.maximumValue)
```

I'm using the minimumValue and maximumValue attributes of QgsRasterBandStats. All the attributes are [listed in the documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsRasterBandStats.html).

In this raster layer I'm working with, there are really only 7 raster values. If I go into the symbology and manually classify these values, you can see them below.

[image]

What I'd really like to do is capture these values in a list, for example. Is there a way to access the individual pixel values in a raster object using QgsRasterBandStats?

Or could I choose a raster value (155 for example) and print the number of pixels with that value? Using something like the following pseudocode?

```
desired_value = 155
print(count of pixels with desired_value)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that by using 'block' method from **QgsRasterDataProvider** for accessing the individual pixel values in a raster object. Below code adds necessary lines to your code for producing each desired counts.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
print("Active Layer: ", layer.name())
provider = layer.dataProvider()
extent = layer.extent()
stats = provider.bandStatistics(1, QgsRasterBandStats.All) 
print("min value =", stats.minimumValue)
print("max value =", stats.maximumValue)

provider = layer.dataProvider()

extent = provider.extent()

rows = layer.height()
cols = layer.width()

block = provider.block(1, extent, cols, rows)

values = [ [] for i in range(rows) ]

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        values[i].append(block.value(i,j))

flattened_list = [ element for list in values for element in list ]

unique = [ flattened_list[i] for i in range(len(flattened_list)) if flattened_list[i] not in flattened_list[:i] ]

for item in unique:
    count = 0

    for element in flattened_list:
        if element == item:
            count += 1

    print ("value: ", item, "count: ", count)
```

I tried above code out with a random raster with only ten values (between 1 and 10) and result, printed at Python Console, it was as follow:

```
Active Layer:  random_raster
min value = 1.0
max value = 10.0
value:  8.0 count:  38
value:  2.0 count:  51
value:  3.0 count:  34
value:  6.0 count:  43
value:  9.0 count:  33
value:  1.0 count:  43
value:  5.0 count:  38
value:  7.0 count:  39
value:  4.0 count:  41
value:  10.0 count:  40
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [QgsRasterInterface.histogram](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.6/core/QgsRasterInterface.html?highlight=qgsrasterinterface#qgis.core.QgsRasterInterface.histogram) to calculate lists of unique values and their respective counts. That's how the paletted/unique values renderer obtains its list of unique values, but using the API gives you the pixel count for each also.

Comment: Hi Nyall, we're having trouble figuring out how to use histograms based on the PyQGIS documenation https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/319267/187