# Using QgsRasterInterface.histogram

Tags: pyqgis

This is really a question of how to better understand QGIS API documentation (C++ or Python) but I'll use this example:

How do I use `QgsRasterInterface.histogram`? I was told in [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311047/pyqgis-raster-band-stats-access-pixel-values-of-raster-layer) I can use `QgsRasterInterface.histogram` to calculate a list of unique values and their counts in a raster layer.

My best attempt so far:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()        #the active layer is a raster layer
provider = layer.dataProvider()

print(provider.hasHistogram(1, 127))   #returns false, no histogram yet

provider.histogram(1)    #for band 1
```

and QGIS crashes. No errors or other information, just a crash. I see that `QgsRasterInterface` has a method `.initHistogram`. Maybe I need to initialize the histogram first?:

[image]

The first argument of `.initHistogram` is a [QgsRasterHistogram](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsRasterHistogram.html). I am unsure how to make this `QgsRasterHistogram` object. The documentation for this class lists no methods. Though it does have some attributes which are inherited from `QgsRasterInterface`, and none of the attributes have an description. The `QgsRasterHistogram` has a short description which makes me think I am on the right path:

[image]

By doing a quick test I can see I have not constructed the `QgsRasterHistogram` properly.

```
histogram = QgsRasterHistogram()
print(histogram.extent)     #prints empty extent
```

The documentation is mostly empty for `QgsRasterHistogram` and when I try to use it in the PyQGIS console, I am not prompted to add any arguments or anything.

Do I need to use `.initHistogram` to construct a histogram for this raster layer?  Or is there another reason QGIS crashes when I use `provider.histogram`?

Answer (score 6):

If you are executing your Python code inside the QGIS Python console, there is already an existing object called `iface` that you can use.

For stand-alone scripts, see [Why does iface.activeLayer() not work in a PyQGis standalone app?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164276/why-does-iface-activelayer-not-work-in-a-pyqgis-standalone-app)

```
l = iface.activeLayer()
p = l.dataProvider()
p.initHistogram(QgsRasterHistogram(),1,100)
h = p.histogram(1)
```

returns

```
<qgis._core.QgsRasterHistogram object at 0x0000016D963189D8>
```

Afterwards accessing some histogram values, such as `h.minimum` and `h.maximum` works but when running

```
h.histogramVector
```

QGIS crashes, so I've created a ticket: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21885 but it's well possible that there's something missing from the Python code here ...

Comment: Thank you for the example. One more question, what does histogramVector do?  There is no information in the documentation.

Comment: @ErichPurpur based on Nyall's answer to your previous question, I expect that some property of the histogram has to give you access to the computed distribution and histogramVector seems to be the most likely candidate

Comment: `h.histogramVector` works for me (3.9 nightly, Windows 10, using IPyConsole plugin from git). It returns a list of length `h.bins` containing count integers.

Comment: Ah, it was fixed. OP's bug report got ported to here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29700

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding an alternate solution to my question. This is a workaround to the .initHistogram() method as it seems to be broken. It is actually a solution I adapted from another StackOverflow thread of mine. Here is the original thread: [PyQGIS Raster Band Stats - Access pixel values of raster layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311047/pyqgis-raster-band-stats-access-pixel-values-of-raster-layer)

Basically what I am trying to do is to re-create the properties > symbology tab, but programmatically. Using the symbology tab allows you to see the color, raster values, and a histogram of those raster values for a given raster layer. Here is an example of what it looks like: 
[image]

The block() method from QgsRasterBandStats class allows you to work with the individual pixels in a raster layer, creating a [QgsRasterBlock](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsRasterBlock.html) object. Here is a code example of reading a raster layer, using the block() method, and accessing the pixels. Also, I'm using a really tiny clip of a raster layer, for the sake of this example. If you are iterating over a raster with many thousands or millions of pixels, this could take a while:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
provider = layer.dataProvider()
stats = provider.bandStatistics(1, QgsRasterBandStats.All) 

extent = layer.extent()
rows = layer.height()
columns = layer.width()
block = provider.block(1, extent, columns, rows)

values = []
for row in range(rows):
    values.append([])
print(f"Values: {values}")

for row in range(rows):
    for column in range(columns):
        values[row].append(block.value(row, column))
print(f"Values: {values}")

flattened_list = []
for list in values:
    for element in list:
        flattened_list.append(element)

unique_values = []
for item in flattened_list:
    if item not in unique_values:
        unique_values.append(item)
print(f"Unique Values: {unique_values}")

for item in unique_values:
    count = 0
    for element in flattened_list:
        if element == item:
            count += 1
    print(f"Value: {item}, Count: {count}")
```

Here is an example of what the output should look like:
[image]