# Setting Bin Count in QgsRasterHistogram

Tags: raster, pyqgis, statistics, histogram

Following this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319163/how-to-use-qgsrasterinterface-histogram/319267#319267), I am trying to use **QgsRasterHistogram** to obtain a histogram of my raster image. However, I cannot figure out how to change bin count.

I looked at the docs [here](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsRasterHistogram.html), and it would seem to me that when calling

```py
l = iface.activeLayer()
p = l.dataProvider()
p.initHistogram(QgsRasterHistogram(),1,100)
h = p.histogram(1)
```

the second parameter in **initHistogram** is the band number, and the third is bin count. However, no matter what number I put as third parameter,

```py
h.binCount
```

always returns 1000. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **h.binCount** is a fixed value that represents the length of **h.histogramVector**. In other words, it is the number of possible classes of grouped values between **h.minimum** and **h.maximum**.

It can be observed with following code and three examples.

```
l = iface.activeLayer()
p = l.dataProvider()
#regardless third parameter
p.initHistogram(QgsRasterHistogram(),1,100)
h = p.histogram(1)

print(h.minimum, h.maximum)
print(h.histogramVector)
print(len(h.histogramVector))
```

With following raster (values between 1 and 10):

[image]

there are 122588 one values, 123084 two values, 123258 three values and so on. Printed value for **h.binCount** is precisely 10.

Following raster has only 25 cells but, its values are between 0 and 10. So, length of **h.histogramVector** and **h.binCount** is in this case 11.

[image]

Concluding, as your **h.binCount** command always returns 1000 as result, you should have 1000 classes of grouped values in your **h.histogramVector** (where some values can be counted as zero).

It can be visualized with result obtained for a bigger raster:

[image]

The length of **h.histogramVector** has a maximum of 1000 as in your case. So, I think that 1000 is the maximum number of classes to be grouped in a **QgsRasterHistogram** object.

> >1650.0 3226.0
>
> [1, 0, 2, 4, 4, 1, 5, 0, 3, 3, 6, 9, 0, 9, 4, 10, 6, 1, 7, 2, 13, 2,
>   4, 7, 1, 10, 3, 5, 1, 15, 14, 3, 10, 5, 6, 5, 2, 12, 2, 6, 0, 7, 17,
>   3, 7, 6, 13, 9, 19, 16, 8, 18, 7, 21, 12, 15, 19, 8, 15, 14, 11, 12,
>   13, 20, 6, 13, 16, 14, 19, 6, 10, 11, 17, 12, 26, 20, 9, 21, 8, 28,
>   12, 31, 19, 29, 25, 16, 33, 9, 21, 30, 13, 27, 15, 32, 26, 9, 44, 11,
>   31, 21, 29, 36, 18, 40, 33, 45, 31, 21, 41, 15, 41, 21, 39, 46, 14,
>   39, 13, 50, 16, 46, 38, 21, 46, 11, 39, 11, 55, 52, 14, 34, 30, 40,
>   42, 14, 41, 22, 38, 22, 53, 41, 19, 36, 38, 45, 17, 41, 45, 27, 30,
>   33, 36, 55, 22, 44, 25, 48, 28, 38, 51, 28, 43, 31, 66, 21, 52, 53,
>   15, 63, 21, 51, 18, 43, 58, 26, 46, 23, 55, 48, 44, 49, 15, 63, 30,
>   52, 74, 23, 57, 30, 58, 21, 60, 40, 22, 55, 23, 54, 17, 69, 58, 34,
>   53, 36, 61, 64, 22, 55, 42, 55, 39, 51, 64, 34, 84, 24, 89, 34, 66,
>   65, 19, 75, 34, 63, 55, 29, 71, 27, 64, 20, 81, 68, 34, 63, 26, 57,
>   31, 65, 54, 29, 64, 37, 70, 35, 51, 63, 30, 56, 29, 60, 68, 18, 57,
>   29, 57, 33, 65, 60, 23, 50, 26, 44, 17, 59, 57, 20, 53, 21, 37, 52,
>   40, 48, 25, 54, 26, 50, 54, 22, 56, 27, 55, 24, 50, 51, 23, 44, 12,
>   46, 19, 42, 50, 31, 50, 19, 57, 31, 13, 32, 16, 61, 23, 47, 43, 23,
>   35, 30, 35, 20, 43, 42, 16, 31, 21, 51, 17, 34, 36, 22, 39, 16, 50,
>   36, 23, 53, 18, 50, 12, 23, 50, 16, 38, 33, 41, 17, 50, 29, 10, 32,
>   28, 37, 50, 18, 27, 13, 38, 22, 34, 37, 21, 41, 21, 35, 15, 35, 30,
>   17, 36, 14, 36, 8, 39, 45, 10, 35, 15, 49, 27, 17, 26, 13, 29, 16, 35,
>   27, 13, 47, 11, 43, 13, 30, 34, 21, 44, 13, 37, 38, 22, 29, 13, 38,
>   20, 33, 48, 21, 29, 19, 36, 21, 39, 31, 17, 32, 15, 28, 19, 43, 28,
>   16, 48, 17, 39, 26, 16, 50, 18, 31, 17, 33, 27, 12, 29, 20, 40, 27,
>   44, 39, 14, 40, 13, 50, 7, 29, 39, 11, 35, 12, 32, 29, 26, 30, 18, 49,
>   16, 34, 34, 23, 19, 25, 27, 19, 26, 35, 15, 32, 19, 38, 27, 14, 34,
>   12, 29, 18, 33, 27, 12, 45, 18, 33, 17, 38, 25, 17, 31, 8, 31, 25, 27,
>   46, 9, 18, 20, 23, 41, 17, 30, 11, 27, 19, 34, 25, 15, 24, 7, 32, 18,
>   23, 26, 21, 26, 15, 29, 16, 34, 26, 18, 15, 15, 25, 28, 18, 29, 18,
>   19, 12, 22, 19, 13, 29, 10, 29, 10, 23, 10, 16, 30, 21, 30, 32, 18,
>   25, 5, 29, 13, 29, 23, 18, 20, 6, 26, 15, 16, 19, 5, 24, 14, 11, 13,
>   20, 28, 3, 26, 24, 37, 36, 12, 21, 5, 25, 7, 24, 14, 10, 16, 17, 18,
>   15, 18, 25, 15, 36, 12, 23, 27, 6, 22, 12, 19, 19, 25, 32, 9, 34, 8,
>   20, 10, 24, 25, 12, 23, 14, 27, 13, 13, 21, 12, 25, 10, 23, 23, 18,
>   14, 17, 23, 10, 25, 28, 10, 25, 6, 17, 14, 29, 43, 9, 14, 9, 20, 19,
>   11, 20, 8, 19, 8, 17, 26, 12, 21, 17, 26, 10, 20, 9, 10, 28, 9, 21, 9,
>   17, 19, 10, 18, 11, 14, 16, 8, 31, 5, 18, 8, 19, 6, 14, 19, 3, 27, 18,
>   19, 17, 9, 18, 4, 8, 8, 21, 18, 9, 12, 13, 32, 2, 8, 14, 7, 22, 12,
>   13, 22, 8, 22, 7, 13, 12, 17, 15, 7, 22, 4, 14, 10, 7, 15, 3, 15, 17,
>   9, 14, 6, 17, 9, 10, 10, 17, 29, 8, 4, 11, 8, 9, 12, 18, 13, 21, 6,
>   18, 15, 12, 24, 6, 25, 9, 15, 15, 7, 12, 15, 18, 9, 12, 16, 9, 19, 6,
>   12, 4, 13, 16, 6, 23, 4, 15, 8, 4, 13, 12, 18, 8, 14, 13, 4, 14, 6,
>   11, 9, 12, 8, 12, 16, 3, 7, 6, 9, 9, 7, 11, 8, 14, 9, 4, 16, 5, 12, 2,
>   16, 8, 5, 4, 2, 12, 6, 11, 11, 7, 10, 4, 11, 13, 7, 5, 5, 12, 0, 16,
>   10, 4, 7, 10, 5, 3, 9, 1, 1, 8, 2, 14, 9, 3, 10, 7, 6, 4, 13, 13, 3,
>   3, 5, 10, 3, 10, 14, 2, 5, 6, 7, 3, 7, 5, 4, 7, 5, 4, 13, 3, 10, 3, 9,
>   2, 6, 4, 4, 9, 4, 2, 6, 5, 15, 4, 7, 3, 2, 3, 7, 3, 3, 4, 2, 6, 5, 1,
>   5, 2, 4, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 0, 5, 6, 4, 1, 0, 5, 6, 4, 2, 1, 3, 0,
>   5, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 0, 1, 4, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1,
>   0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
>   0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
>   0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2]
>
> > 1000
>
> >h.binCount
>
> >1000

Comment: Thank you @xunilk, this is very clear. So is there another way I can get hold of ALL possible values of a raster image? And also, is there a way to know what value (not the count, the actual value counted) corresponds to each item in the  h.histogramVector list?

Comment: You can use 'block' method from **QgsRasterDataProvider** that produces a **QgsRasterBlock** object. So,  you can get hold of ALL possible values of a raster image.